# Flash AS3, strangeness when setting position of child movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm dynamically adding movieclip objects to a parent container and then setting each newly added clip's y position to the height of the container plus some number of vertical padding pixels.  The desired effect is to append the new movieclip to the bottom of a vertical column of movieclips (a text message thread).  What's strange is that no matter what value I specify for vertical padding, the new clip is always displayed abutted exactly against the bottom of the previously added clip, as though the padding were always 0.

```
var smsVPadding:Number = 10;

// Get current bounds of sms_history_mc
var bounds = sms_history_mc.getBounds( sms_history_mc.parent );
var yPos:Number = bounds.height + smsVPadding;

// Add the new SMS to sms_history_mc
sms_history_mc.addChild( newSMS );

newSMS.y = yPos;
```

If I set the value of newSMS.y explicitly to a number `newSMS.y = 600` it works as expected.  However, if I set yPos by explicitly adding the padding pixels  `bounds.height + 10` the result is strange again.

`trace(newSMS.y)` yields the expected value, but the movielip's position does not reflect this.

Any thoughts?  Please tell me I'm missing something ridiculous.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the content inside your sms object/MovieClip is positioned properly?   Sounds like you may have some empty space at the top of that clip.   Also, no reason to use bounds, just do `sms_history_mc.height`

Comment: Maybe it's because you've set the first movieclip's `y` to the padding value, so all the clips are just shifted down by 10 pixels.

Comment: @BolesławChrobry  nailed it.  That 10 pixels of empty space at the top of your `sms_history_mc` is what's throwing it off.  The height/width of the object doesn't reflect any empty space on the top/bottom/left/right of the clip

Comment: @LDMS You're right about bounds being unnecessary - that's a bit of legacy code from some earlier logic - now changed, thx.  As for the positioning of the contents of the sms movieclip, it all looks good.

Comment: @BoleslawChrobry Right.  I see what you're saying.  Will test momentarily

Comment: Yep.  Thanks all.  I did as you to tell me I was missing something ridiculous.

Comment: Not sure what protocol is for posting revised code including fix

Answer (score 0):

My problem was, as @BoleslawChrobry pointed out, the 10 pixels of padding added to the first mc were in effect "trimmed" from the height of the containing mc next time it was calculated.  Easy fix:

```
// Get current bounds of sms_history_mc
var bounds = sms_history_mc.getBounds( sms_history_mc.parent );
var yPos:Number = sms_history_mc.height;
if( yPos > 0 ) // At least one sms has already been added
     yPos += smsVPadding;

// Add the new SMS to sms_history_mc
sms_history_mc.addChild( newSMS );

newSMS.y = yPos;
```